# Umbraco remove a tag in riche editor

Tags: umbraco

i have reachtext editor field in my template under Umbraco CMS.
What I put some code like it

```
 <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse_1"><p>My text</p></a>
```

and save content, reachtext editor remove *a* tag and save only

My text

text information.

I know what this is not valid href from HTML standarts if I remove

tag all working fine.

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes allowing unrestricted mark-up in the editor can lead to undesired results or allows a bit more control than you might want to give to editors. I'm guessing that it is the data attributes that are causing the results you see and so you can if you wish just allow those attributes on the anchor tag by modifying the list of allowed tags in your tinyMceConfig.config file.

You will find the file in your config directory, open it up and skip down to the  element towards the bottom of the file. You will find that the anchor tag is the first element defined as follows:

```
+a[id|style|rel|rev|charset|hreflang|dir|lang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title|class|onfocus|onblur|onclick|ondblclick|onmousedown|onmouseup|onmouseover|onmousemove|onmouseout|onkeypress|onkeydown|onkeyup]
```

The list of allowed attributes are what is defined inside of the square brackets so you could try to append "data-parent" and "data-toggle" attributes to the end of the list separated by the pipe character as follows:

```
+a[id|style|rel|rev|charset|hreflang|dir|lang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title|class|onfocus|onblur|onclick|ondblclick|onmousedown|onmouseup|onmouseover|onmousemove|onmouseout|onkeypress|onkeydown|onkeyup|data-toggle|data-toggle]
```

Comment: Good one @Pronotion, I agree completely. I assumed it would be TidyHTML getting upset over the `p` inside an `a` but this is valid of course.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this is how the RTE is expected to work. Secondly, if you want to override this behaviour you must override it for the entire Umbraco application.

This article explains how to do it: [http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/customizing-the-wysiwyg-rich-text-editor-(tinymce)/allow-any-markup-in-the-tinymce-editor](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/customizing-the-wysiwyg-rich-text-editor-%28tinymce%29/allow-any-markup-in-the-tinymce-editor)

In a nutshell, in the config/umbracoSettings.config file, find and set the following line:

```
<TidyEditorContent>False</TidyEditorContent>
```

Then, change the `validElements` line to:

```
<validElements><![CDATA[*[*]]]></validElements>
```

**Edit:**

As Pronotion states in the accepted answer, this should really only be used when full control is needed over the markup added into the RTE, and it could lead to undesired results.

Comment: I can confirm on Umbraco 7+ this does not seem to make a difference. TinyMCE strips out code before the content is even saved/published.